# How to change the size of a plot/graph in python

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

I would like to change the size of a  graph (with multiple plots) in python to make it larger. using 'plt.figure(figsize=(6,3))' for example makes a new graph of a different size but its empty with just the axes, the actual plots do not show. can someone help me understand where i am going wrong? i have attached an image of my code in this question. thank you in advance [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qibr3.png)

Comment: `plt.figure(figuresize=size))` should work. Can you provide minimum reproducible code where you tried this and didn't work so we can check if there is something else wrong in the code? Please don't send the code as image.

Comment: I have seen where i was going wrong and was able to fix the code. Thank you very much for the reply

Comment: The keyword is `figsize`, though. And don't post code/data as images - always post the text directly here on SO.

Comment: **[No Screenshots](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/)** of code or data. Always provide a [mre] with code, **data, errors, current output, and expected output**, as **[formatted text](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting)**. If relevant, plot images are okay. Please see [How to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 4):

Always write the `plt.figure(figsize=(x,y))` before the line of code that will create the plot and end it by `plt.show()`